# Where is torch::col2im defined in pytorch source code?

Tags: c++, pytorch, namespaces

Recently, when I looked at the source code of pytorch and found that torch::col2im was used in fold.h（https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/a012216b960c5c31ca2a56a47da454d105764895/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/nn/functional/fold.h  line 18）.

```
#include <torch/nn/options/fold.h>

namespace torch {
namespace nn {
namespace functional {

...

if (input.dim() == 3 || input.dim() == 2) {
    return torch::col2im(
        input,
        output_size,
        kernel_size,
        dilation,
        padding,
        stride);
  }
...
```

However, I did not find the definition of  col2im under the **torch namespace** in the source code. Instead, I found **at::native::col2im** in im2col.h（https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/0a07488ed2c47765e337e290bd138c0e6e459cbd/aten/src/ATen/native/im2col.h  line 54）.

```
#include <ATen/ATen.h>
#include <ATen/TensorUtils.h>
#include <ATen/Utils.h>
#include <c10/util/irange.h>

#include <algorithm>

namespace at {
namespace native {

...

template <typename T>
static void col2im(
    const T* data_col,
    const int64_t channels,
    const int64_t height,
    const int64_t width,
    const int64_t output_height,
    const int64_t output_width,
    const int64_t kernel_h,
    const int64_t kernel_w,
    const int64_t pad_h,
    const int64_t pad_w,
    const int64_t stride_h,
    const int64_t stride_w,
    const int64_t dilation_h,
    const int64_t dilation_w,
    T* data_im) {
...
```

Confusingly, I did not find how the two are related in the '#include' of fold.h. Obviously, the source code can be compiled successfully. Then how to explain that col2im is generated. Is there anything I've overlooked in compiling and linking?

Answer (score 0):

There's loads of generated code in PyTorch. In this case, the two are connected through the code generated from `native_functions.yaml`. You can see that `im2col` dispatches to `im2col_cpu` for CPU inputs and to `im2col_cuda` for CUDA inputs. Then, from those functions, you can follow the functions they call until you get to the actual CPU / CUDA kernels.